# SELECT INTO where source data are in other database than target table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I execute `SELECT INTO` query where my source data are in other database than the table I insert to (but on the same server).

When I execute the query using the same database where my source data are (`USE DATABASE_MY_SOURCE_DATA`), it completes in under a minute. When I change the database to the database where my target table sits, it doesn't complete in 10 minutes (I don't know the exact time because I cancelled it).

Why is that? Why is the difference so huge? I can't get my head around it.

Comment: The SQL engine needs to move data from the remote database.  This affects how the query can be optimized.

Comment: Upload the XML of the execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question.

Comment: try using linked servers

Comment: But these two databases are on the same server

Comment: We cannot help you unless you provide the query, the index definitions, and share the two query plans as mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying cross-database, even using a linked server connection, is always likely (at least in 2021) to present performance concerns.

The first problem is that the optimizer doesn't have access to estimate the number of rows in the remote table(s). It's also going to miss indexes on those tables, resorting to table scans (which tend to be a lot slower on large tables than index seeks).

Another issue is that there is no data caching, so the optimizer makes round-trips to the remote database for every necessary operation.

More information (from a great source):
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/07/why-are-linked-server-queries-so-bad/

Assuming that you want this to be more performant, and that you are doing substantial filtering on the remote data source, you may see some performance benefit from creating - on the remote database - a view that filters to just the rows you want on the target table and query that for your results.

Alternatively (and likely more correctly) you should wrap these operations in an ETL process (such as SSIS) that better manages these connections.